# How to make a Nested Json Model in Vapor Swift Server , Below are the Code for the reference..?

Tags: swift, swift3, backend, vapor

Friend model contain the address reference. Address is saving but not able to retrieve from the end point.

**Friend Model**

```
        import Foundation
        import Vapor
        import Fluent

        struct Friend: Model {
            var exists: Bool = false
            var id: Node?
            var name: String
            var age: Int
            var email: String
            var residence: FriendAddress

            init(name: String, age: Int, email: String, residence: FriendAddress) {
                self.name = name
                self.age = age
                self.email = email
                self.residence = residence
            }

            // NodeInitializable
            init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
                id = try node.extract("_id")
                name = try node.extract("name")
                age = try node.extract("age")
                email = try node.extract("email")
                residence = try node.extract("residence")
            }

            // NodeRepresentable
            func makeNode(context: Context) throws -> Node {
                return try Node(node: ["_id": id,
                                       "name": name,
                                       "age": age,
                                       "email": email,
                                       "residence": residence
                    ])
            }

            // Preparation
            static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
                try database.create("friends") { friends in
                    friends.id()
                    friends.string("name")
                    friends.int("age")
                    friends.string("email")
                    friends.string("residence")
                }
            }

            static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
                try database.delete("friends")
            }
        }
```

Friend Address Model contains owner_id acting as a foreign key (Friend Model)

**Friend Addresss Model**

```
    import Foundation
    import Vapor
    import Fluent

    struct FriendAddress: Model {

        var id: Node?
        var owner_id: Node?
        var address: String
        var address2: String
        var pinCode: Int

        init(address: String, address2: String, pinCode: Int, owner_id: Node? = nil ) {
            self.address = address
            self.address2 = address2
            self.pinCode = pinCode
            self.owner_id = owner_id
        }

        // NodeInitializable
        init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
            id = try node.extract("_id")
            address = try node.extract("address")
            address2 = try node.extract("address2")
            pinCode = try node.extract("pinCode")
            owner_id = try node.extract("owner_id")

        }

        // NodeRepresentable
        func makeNode(context: Context) throws -> Node {

            return try Node(node: [
                        "_id": id,
                        "address": address,
                        "address2": address2,
                        "pinCode": pinCode,
                        "owner_id": owner_id])
        }

        // Preparation
        static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
            try database.create("friendAddress") { friendaddress in
                friendaddress.id()
                friendaddress.string("address")
                friendaddress.int("address2")
                friendaddress.string("pinCode")
                friendaddress.parent(Friend.self, optional: false)

            }
        }

        static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
            try database.delete("friendAddress")
        }
    }
```

**main.swift**

```
import Vapor
import VaporMongo
import Fluent

import Foundation

let drop = Droplet()
//drop.preparations.append(Friend.self)
drop.preparations = [Friend.self, FriendAddress.self, Pivot<Friend, FriendAddress>.self]

do {
    try drop.addProvider(VaporMongo.Provider.self)
} catch {
    assertionFailure("Error adding provider: \(error)")
}

let friendController = FriendController()
friendController.addRoutes(drop: drop)

drop.resource("posts", PostController())
drop.run()
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, when you try to retrieve the address using the children() method on a Friend, you don't get anything?


Please show us the columns of the "friendAddress" table.


My guess is that the final column created by fluent is named "friend_id" and not owner_id, hence when you try to save an address you save it with an invalid owner_id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a model in vapor using Mongokitten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588402/how-to-create-a-model-in-vapor-using-mongokitten)