# How to create a model in vapor using Mongokitten

Tags: mongodb, swift3, vapor

**This is the model and I have to change it to mongo model using mongokitten.**

This is my friend Model and I have implemented.
This but not able to make a nested json like structure for this mode.

```
import Foundation
import Vapor
import Fluent

     struct Friend: Model {
        var exists: Bool = false
        var id: Node?
        var name: String
        var age: Int
        var email: String
        var residence: FriendAddress

        init(name: String, age: Int, email: String ,residence: FriendAddress) {
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
            self.email = email
            self.residence = residence
        }

        // NodeInitializable
        init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
            id = try node.extract("_id")
            name = try node.extract("name")
            age = try node.extract("age")
            email = try node.extract("email")
            residence = try node.extract("residence")
        }

        // NodeRepresentable
        func makeNode(context: Context) throws -> Node {
            return try Node(node: ["_id": id,
                                   "name": name,
                                   "age": age,
                                   "email": email,
    //                               "residence": residence
                ])
        }

        // Preparation
        static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
            try database.create("friends") { friends in
                friends.id("_id")
                friends.string("name")
                friends.int("age")
                friends.string("email")
                friends.string("residence")
            }
        }

        static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
            try database.delete("friends")
        }
    }
```

basically need a json structure like this,

for eg:

```
{    
"name": "anil",
 "age": 12,
  "   email": "anilklal91@gmail.com",
     "residence": {
    "address": "first address 1",
    "address2": "second address 2",
    "pinCode" : 110077
     }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [MCVE]. I suggest reading [ask].

Comment: @DavidGlickman i have tried and edited the post for the reference..need help in achieving the solution of the problem, not expecting to code for me..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a model into JSON, the best way is to conform your model to [`JSONRepresentable`](https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/json/overview/#representable). In this case, you should conform both `Friend` and `FriendAddress`.

A possible way to implement it for your `Friend` model:

```
func makeJSON() throws -> JSON {
    var json = JSON()
    try json.set("name", name)
    try json.set("age", age)
    try json.set("email", email)
    try json.set("residence", residence)
    return json
}
```

Note that it nests `residence` using `FriendAddress`'s implementation of `makeJSON()`.